# Where can I find scala documentation which list all available method in String class

Tags: scala

I was going through the api documentation page of scala but could not find string class specific method, may be I am missing something. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: What method did you find? It may be method of `java.lang.String` or some implicit method from scala library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scala.Predef` defines two implicit conversions from `String`: one to [WrappedString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) and another to [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps).

You will find all the String related methods in these two classes.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what i was searching. Sorry could not upvote your answer as i don't have enough reputation points.